# What are you most excited to see at SPC?

Tags: development

What topics are you most excited to see at the SharePoint Conference (2009)?

For me, I am curious to see how the developer story is playing out as well as the good conversation with folks around what is released about the new development tools at the conference.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the limitations of the current product have been resolved around the platform not just from a developer perspective but also from Enterprise perspective too. [Check out my thoughts so far](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11403336) and also [my post on it](http://wss.made4the.net/archive/2009/10/09/sharepoint-2010-the-enterprise-platform.aspx). All of which will help me pitch SharePoint as a Development Platform for the Enterprise.

Oh and meeting you Rob and having a beer in Vegas ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in SharePoint (both WSS and MOSS) for public-facing internet sites. The big issues with the V3 product are:

- Performance
- Deployment
- Accessibility

So I will be looking forward to seeing what the product team did to address those issues in v2010, asking questions of people who know the inside story, and of course going crazy in Las Vegas!

Answer (score 1):

As i won't be there i will have to say, what i will mostly be looking out for on twitter, blogs, webcasts etc.

I am very interested in how the UI has been changed especially given the new ribbon. I am hoping the blogs and wikis have been updated to be more competative with some of the more popular open source alternatives.

What have they done with mysites?

Will it make my life better and make me a millionairre. :)

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mattmoo, keen to see what the UI looks like, from the backend too.  Standards compliance in CSS (ie. using DIVs instead of tables).  Also, if they are taking advantage of some of the new SQL stuff, like Filestream, so that we can have large files in Doc Libs.

Will it make me breakfast in bed?  Hehehe.

Comment: Mattmoo and Flamer, in one of our Road2SPC shows for the SharePoint Pod Show, I sat down and talked with the Product Manager of WSS and asked him about the changes to the UI.  Stay tuned, it will be live in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really interested in seeing various upgrade scenarios from v3/2007 to 2010. Obviously the claim is that it will be "streamlined", but I have a hard time believing that without seeing anything tangible. For most of us consultants, we will be tasked with upgrading our current clients within the next 1-2 years, so I would think that this topic is something that we will want to follow closely.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to networking with clients, partners, vendors, and other SharePoint professionals; my goal is to understand what MSFT has done to mature SharePoint as a product/platform and review products and tools from vendors so I can better advise clients. Man have we come a long way from Thursday, November 16, 2006.

Answer (score 0):

I won't make it in person, but I'm excited to hear the big announcements Monday morning and throughout the week.

The keynote address Monday by Microsoft CEO Steve Ballmer and VP of SharePoint Jeff Teper will be streamed live from [the conference website](http://www.mssharepointconference.com)